# Dynamic Binding with subclasses "no suitable method found"

Tags: java, oop, dynamic-binding

B extends A, C extends A

trying to change:

```
   public void convertA(A a) {

    AClass clazz = new AClass();

    if (a instanceof B) {
        clazz.setX(convertBtoX(a));
    } else if (a instanceof C) {
        clazz.setY(convertCtoY(a));
    }

}
```

to

```
public void convertAbis(A a) {

    AClass clazz = fill(a); //ERROR NO SUITABLE METHOD FOUND FOR FILL

}


public AClass fill(B b) {
     clazz.setX(convertBtoX(b));
}

public AClass fill(C c) {
    clazz.setY(convertCtoY(c));
}
```

results in a "no suitable method found for fill" error.
How could I remove the "instance of" switch?
**A, B, C are Data Trasfer Object and should not be aware about X Y and viceversa so I can't simply add fill methode to A,B,C classes**.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`fill(a)` will not automatically match the B and C args, but looking for `fill(A a)`.

To sove your problem, try below.

First create a abstract function `void fill(AClass c)` in class `A`.

Create this function in class `B`:

```
public void fill(AClass clazz){
    clazz.setX(convertBtoX(this));
}
```

And do almost the same to class `C`.

```
public void fill(AClass clazz){
    clazz.setY(convertCtoY(c));
}
```

Then use as this:

```
void convertABis(A a){
     AClass clazz = new AClass();
     a.fill(clazz);
}
```

Comment: "A, B, C are Data Trasfer Object and should not be aware about X Y and viceversa so I can't simply add fill methode to A,B,C classes."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `A` is not a subclass of `B` or `C`, but there are `B` and `C` that are subclasses of `A`. So, passing an object of type `A` to methods `fill` is not possibile.